# Android Intent Service class getSystemService nullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, nullpointerexception

I have an intent service class which is used to scan for devices on the wifi network. I'm fairly new to android btw. But I thought I set it up as simply as possible, since I'll just be assigning to a list without UI work needed.

```
public class NetHelper extends IntentService {

    public NetHelper() {
        super("network-helper");

        listDevices = new ArrayList<Devices>();
        myContext = this;

        cm = (ConnectivityManager) myContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        manager = (WifiManager) myContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        connectionInfo = manager.getConnectionInfo();

        MYNET_IP = Formatter.formatIpAddress(connectionInfo.getIpAddress());
    }
}
```

My onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {} is just calling an inner class method but. and here is my call from main activity:

```
    public void launchNetworkSniffer() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NetHelper.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }
```

My application thus crashes witha  null exception when calling getSystemService. I have tried many forms of calls including getApplicationContext, this, and nothing at all. OnCreate is not overridden, but I tried to override with this.OnCreate() but still no luck.

my error is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: **update: resolved** for any other newbies that struggle with this. getApplicationContext() does not work in the IntentService class' constructor. So I moved my code to the onIntentHandler() and voila. But the question still remains. __why__ does getApplicationContext() return null anywhere except inside onIntentHandler()?

Comment: `getSystemService()` returns `null` from the constructor. It will return a non-`null` value from most other callbacks (e.g., `onCreate()`). The `Service` is not ready for use until `onCreate()` is called, which includes calling most inherited methods. Other than chain to the superclass, the constructor of an `IntentService` should do nothing, in general.

Comment: Perfect. I broke the fundamental rule of constructors (keep it simple). and for that I feel silly. Thanks for the explanation!